# Replacing values in Numpy array based on permutations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large np array called **X** (size:32000) filled with duplicate values of `0, 1, 2, 3`.
I want to replace each of the values(0, 1, 2, 3) with permutations of the following numbers: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`
For example,    `0, 1, 2, 3` can be replaced with following:

```
  1, 5, 3, 4
  5, 2, 4, 3
  0, 5, 1, 4
```

and so on.(there are 360 such permutations in total)

How can I take each of the 360 permutations and replace the 32000 values in **X** accordingly such that finally I have 360 versions of **X** for each permutation?

Comment: The mapping process itself is fairly straight-forward, but your question is not completely clear.  Does this replacement process create 360 new arrays, or do you simply want to create a new one of the 360 modifications on each loop iteration? Also, what is the shape of `X`?

Comment: X is a 1d array with 32000 values. Each of the values are either 0,1,2 or 3. I am trying to create 360 new versions of X that corresponds to each of permutations

Comment: Sorry, that's still not clear. Do you want to create an array of shape (360, 32000) to store those new versions of X? Does BossaNova's answer do what you want? Do you know how to generate the 360 permutations?

Comment: I am trying out BossNovva's answer. No I dont need the shape of 360 by 32000. I need each of the 32000 vales to be replaced by a permutation. for example, one permutation is  1, 5, 3, 4. So, 0s in X  takes value of 1.  1s in X takes value of 5. 2s in X  takes value of 3. 3s in X take value of 4. All 32000 values have been replaced by these new numbers from the permutation 1,5,3,4. Then I do the same for another permutation like 1,3,5,4 and so on.There are 360 such permutations. so I will have to create 360 X arrays with the values from the 360 permutations.

Comment: Why 360 permutations? Because I have 4 unique values (0,1,2,3) in X and I have 6 values for replacement(0,1,2,3,4,5). So, 6P4=360.

Comment: btw, BossNovva's  answer doesnt answer my question

Comment: Why doesn't BossaNova's answer work for you? It performs the substitution you want. Eg, given `x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0])` and `perm = [1, 5, 3, 4]` it sets `x` to `[1 5 3 4 3 4 1 5 4 3 5 1]`. Of course, since you want to permute the original `x` with each of the 6P4 permutations you need to store the results somewhere else, not in `x`, but that's just a minor issue.

Comment: np.choose seems to work because the x follows a pattern 0123,0123... The 32000 values in X are completely random. you can try running the code with completely  random values  in x

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176998/discussion-between-pm-2ring-and-listener).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the method [`numpy.choose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3,]) 
perm = [1, 5, 3, 4,]
x = np.choose(x, perm)
```

np.choose(x, perm) will choose a value from perm for each value of x, taking x as a list of indices. I recommend looking at the documentation since this function can lead to confusion.